# Is there a way to know how many times someone has favorited your question?

Tags: support, bookmarks

Is there any way I can find out how many people have favorited my questions, if any at all have?  It seems to me that this statistic should sit right below "viewed".

Comment: Yes but it's a _secret_.

Comment: That star under the vote buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The star button under the question voting buttons shows you how many people have starred a question:

[image][image]

The same information can be seen in your questions tab:

[image]

If there is no number below the star, then it is not starred by anyone.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can check if someone has favorited your questions by going to your [profile > Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3174746/eric-taylor?tab=questions).  Looking at your profile today, you currently don't have any questions that have been favorited by other users.

But if your questions have been favorited, then you will see a star next to the question and the number of times some has favorited it. It will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/75688/which-questions-of-mine-are-most-favourited to see which questions of yours are favorited.

And you can also use this query https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/28557/who-favorited-my-questions to see which users favorited your questions.

To run either of those queries just enter your UserID which can be found here

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/3174746/eric-taylor
                                ^^^^^ that's your user id!!!!! YAY!
```